# Transpose Python text table into Pandas DF and then in CSV

Tags: python, dataframe, export-to-csv

[![enter image description here][1]][1][![enter image description here][1]][1]By below code prints the HTML web table as python script output.
Then I tried converting it to Pandas DF and then export to CSV but failed

```
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd

url = 'http://www.altrankarlstad.com/wisp'

driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\\Users\\rugupta\\AppData\\Roaming\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs\\Python 3.7\\chromedriver.exe')

driver.get(url)
time.sleep(100) 

text_field = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="root"]/div/div/div/div[2]/table')
#print (text_field[0].text)
data= text_field[0].text
#Works fine until above section

df= pd.DataFrame(data)
df.to_csv("output.csv")
(but no success here)!

[![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NpGk2.jpg
```

Comment: How does it fail? Please provide an error traceback.

Comment: Could you give us a `print` of your `data` variable? I'd rather not enter a website that doesn't even appear on google

Comment: `driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\\driver path')` doesn't look correct

Comment: I provided the details pertaining to all the questions, please let me know if any other details needed.

Comment: Very clearly, I am looking for a CSV which has columns: "Date", "Beskrivning","jobtitle"

Comment: any update from anyone please?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that selenium will detect that the page has been loaded, however, you need it to wait until the table with the data you are trying to scrape has been loaded. So you need to tell selenium to wait until an element in the table has been found. For this particular case each "job" in the table is defined by a particular class name called "css-58'. The solution would like like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
import time
import pandas as pd


url = 'http://www.altrankarlstad.com/wisp'

driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\driver path")
driver.get(url)

# delay is how long to wait on loading the page before it gives up
delay = 600

try:
    wait_for_element = WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'css-58')))
    text_field = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="root"]/div/div/div/div[2]/table')
    data= text_field[0].text

    # Create your dataframe here
    # This will currently fail due to the error
    # ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!
    # You should be able to define the structure of your data frame to suit your needs
    df= pd.DataFrame(data)
    df.to_csv("output.csv")
except TimeoutException:
    print('It took too long')
```

Only thing you should need to do at this point is figure out how you would like to define the structure of your data frame.

Comment: Thanks grlaer!, how could I know what structure my dataframe is..? I guess the data I have is string..